# How to abort thread that use AcceptTcpClient() inside?

Tags: c#

`AcceptTcpClient()` prevents app from exit after I called `thrd.Abort()`.

How to exit application when in listening?

Comment: There is literally no way for us to get an understanding of anything here because you have provided no context. Are you already running this on another thread?

Comment: Yes, started listening in another thread.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to interrupt the call to `AcceptTcpClient()` by closing the `TcpListener` (this will result in an exception being thrown by the blocking `AcceptTcpClient()`. You should *not* be aborting the thread, which is generally a very bad idea in all but a few very specific circumstances.

Here's a brief example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12343);
        var thread = new Thread(() => AsyncAccept(listener));
        thread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping listener...");
        listener.Stop();
        thread.Join();
    }

    private static void AsyncAccept(TcpListener listener)
    {
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Started listener");
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Accepted client: {0}", client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Listener done");
    }
}
```

The code above starts a listener on a separate thread, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the console window will stop the listener, wait for the listener thread to complete, then the application will exit normally, no thread aborts required!

Answer (score 1):

You could:

Use BeginAcceptTcpClient() and End.. instead: 
See:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Or your could:

Create a TcpClient and send your listener message:

therefore (I guess you have a loop in your thread):

- break the loop wherein the listener.AcceptTcpClient() is running.
  (i.e. CancelAsync()) from outside and 
  Loop While (!Tread.CancellationPending);
- Create a TcpClient and send your listener a message (and discard data);
  TcpClient see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx
- Now your thread can go on with: 
  client.close() and listener.stop()